# Possible to skip inlined, named modules with r.js build?

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs, r.js

In my application, I have a named module defined inline in index.html:

```
<script>
    define('config', {
        mode: '...',
        environment: '...',
        apiUrl: '...',
        rootPath: '...',
        baseImageUrl: '...'
    });
</script>
```

I need to define this in my web page because I pull some stuff in using environment variables. So, in my modules, I can then include 'config':

```
define(['config', 'jquery'], function(config, $) { ... });
```

When I run a RequireJS build using Grunt (with [grunt-require](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-require), which uses r.js), it's complaining that it's not finding config.js. My build configuration looks like this:

```
{
    baseUrl: 'js',
    main: 'app/Main',
    dir: 'js/build',
    out: null,
    modules: { ... },
    paths: { ... },
    shim: { ... }
}
```

When I build, I get:

```
Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/projects/projectname/js/build/config.js
```

How can I allow for use of named, inline-defined modules in conjunction with an r.js build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
paths: {
   config : 'empty:'
}
```

in your build configuration file should exclude this module out of optimization process and, as a result, stop raising this error.

But this is a bit tricky way, because this option is commonly used to exclude third-party dependencies (for example, when developing some js library based on Backbone, it would be better to separate your lib from Backbone)